# Нужно ли перезагружать nginx после изменения конфигурационного файла nginx.conf

Tags: apache, nginx

Изменил файл nginx.conf Что необходимо сделать чтобы изменения вступили в силу?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx -t && killall -HUP nginx 
или посмотри есть ли у тебя /etc/init.d/nginx и тогда service nginx reload